# What is the least positive integer $n$ for which $n!$ is divisible by $3^8$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the least positive integer $n$ for which $n!$ is divisible by $3^8$?

I am not sure how to tackle this problem without just putting in random low digits as $n$.

Comment: Well you should have at least 8 3's in your factorial, so $18!=3\cdot3\cdot2\cdot17\cdot16\cdot3\cdot5\cdot14\cdot13\cdot3\cdot4\cdot11 \cdot10\cdot3\cdot3\cdot8\cdot7\cdot3\cdot2\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2$.

Answer (score 7):

An additional $3$ in the prime factorization can only occur, if the number is divisble by $3$. If it is divisible by $9$, $3^2$ occurs additionally, if it is divisible by $27$, $3^3$ occurs aditionally and so on.

$3!$ is divisble by $3$

$6!$ is divisble by $3^2$

$9!$ is divisible by $3^4$

$12!$ is divisible by $3^5$

$15!$ is divisible by $3^6$

$18!$ is divisible by $3^8$

The answer is therefore $18$.